# How to override the tables setting "Use only IAM access control for new tables in this database" while creating glue database using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, overriding, aws-glue, aws-lake-formation

I am trying to create glue database using boto3 and we would like to override the value

"Use only IAM access control for new tables in this database"(This is lake formation setting). Below is the sample code we are using but i couldn't find any example on how to specify key value pairs to override value.

```
   create_request = {
        'DatabaseInput': {
            'Name': 'test_db',
            'Description':'desc test_db',
            'LocationUri': 's3://bucket_name'
        }
    }
```

**boto3.session.Session().client('glue','us-east-1').create_database(create_request)**

I have seen https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_database
We can use parameters to override these values but i couldn't find example of key value pair to override.

Comment: Are you going to override only for one database, or all of LakeFormation ?

Comment: one database only.